# What's wrong in asking this question?

Tags: support, questions, downvotes, new-users

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to 'enter' as soon as you press a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581551/how-to-enter-as-soon-as-you-press-a-key)

Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: there are no details in the question. Where's the code, what operating system are you running it on?

Comment: Question with out effort is always down voted. Be careful before post.

Comment: okay,rather than downvoting it, they should let me know and I would be glad to do that.

Comment: @user3147192 the help centre does talk about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) did you read that before you asked?

Comment: Also, a word to the wise - when you ask "Why was this downvoted" here on meta, and the help center tells you exactly what makes a good question - be prepared for the "meta effect" - since you brought more visibility to it, there's a decent chance it will get downvoted even worse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You make the assumption that, because you have this problem, everyone will have it and know exactly how to solve it because it's such a common issue.

Don't make that assumption.

A question will generally be seen by people following the tags which you used for the question. In this case `c++` and `audio`. Neither one of these tags imply that someone had mapped a key to a sound before and thus met the same issue as you. These tags can be used by such a wide audience that you'll need to be very specific in a question that uses exclusively these two tags, so that you receive proper response.

Failure to do so will almost always lead to downvotes.

Comment: okay. I have edited it now. Can I get rid of the downvotes now?

Comment: @user3147192 I upvoted, but not everyone will. This is a fast paced environment. People come, see a question, act on it, and go away - they don't have to stick around to see if the question is improved based on their downvotes. But the edit will serve well for those with expertise in the tagged technologies - so good thing you improved the question - you might get a great answer!